# How to use materialize-cssc with ts in angular4

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I'm new to npm stuff, currently I'm working on an angular project using typescript. My question is how do I use materialize-css package from http://materializecss.com/? I installed it locally with `npm install materialize-css` but now I don't know how to proceed. I tried to use a simple `<select>` tag  and initialized it with `$('select').material_select()` but I keep on getting this error `error TS2339: Property 'material_select' does not exist on type 'JQuery'`. I also installed jQuery using npm.
Please help. 
Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add materialize (js,css, jquery) in your index.html file and in your `AppComponent` file  add this:

```
declare let $ : any;

@Component({
  //...
})
export class Appcomponent{
  //...
};
```

Comment: I've just tried that but it's not working. pls help guys

Comment: Something else I just noticed, I cant use a method llike `Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000)`

Comment: add this `declare let Materialize : any;` just like the other `$`